# I have 2 different table like user and user_managers,i need to get manager details based on userid

Tags: sql

user table

```
empId       FirstName   
1           a
2           b
3           c
4           d
5           e
```

usermanager table

```
empId        ManagerId  
1             2 
2             null  
3             4 
4             5 
5             3
```

result

```
empid    managerid   firstname
1           2         b
2           null      null
3           4         d
4           5         e
5           3         c
```

Comment: Hint:  `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Why not `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: @B001ᛦ . . . That information should go to the publisher.  You can send it directly to Wiley or send me email at the email on the back cover of the book.

Comment: @GordonLinoff okay

Answer (score 1):

You can use just a `LEFT JOIN` statement with JOIN Condition `u.empID = m.ManagerId`

```
select m.empID, m.managerID, u.FirstName
  from usermanager m
  left join user u on u.empID = m.ManagerId;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/XTZ56999)</kbd>

Comment: thanks,if i am adding where condition   select m.empID, m.managerID, u.FirstName
  from usermanager m
  left join user u on u.empID = m.ManagerId where m.empid=3;             output is  

empid    managerid   firstname
3           4         d
4           5         e
5           3         c

Comment: @paramalasathya you're welcome. sure you can add to the above query by starting `where` keyword.

Comment: if i am adding where condition output look like output is  

empid    managerid   firstname
3           4         d
4           5         e
5           3         c

Comment: @paramalasathya if you try with the demo you'll get `empid managerid firstname 
 3 4 d` only. Do you want to get `empid managerid firstname 3 4 d 4 5 e 5 3 c` ??

Comment: @ Barbaros Özhan yes i want like this output      empid managerid firstname 3 4 d 4 5 e 5 3 c

Comment: @paramalasathya I think you want to have hierarchical query to determine all managers and sub-employees starting from emp_id = 3. For this, Firstly, we should know your DBMS. Secondly this is not in thes scope of this question.

Comment: thanks for your reply ,yes i need hierarchical query to determine all managers and sub-employees starting from emp_id = 3. for this you want tables or any information in my local i created sample table i am testing on those tables

Answer (score 1):

If you also want to see users which doesn't have manager you should use `LEFT JOIN`. If you want to see only the users that have manager previous answers should work for you.
Here is a sample :

```
SELECT U.empId
     , UM.ManagerId
     , U.FirstName
FROM User U
LEFT JOIN UserManager UM ON U.empId = UM.empId
```

Answer (score 0):

it's just a join

```
select (columns that you want)
from user u, user_manager um
where u.empId = um.empId
```

Comment: _it's just a join..._ Huh? Where is your `JOIN`?

Comment: my where statement is a natural join

Comment: You meant a CROSS JOIN - However....whenever you catch yourself using `WHERE` in relation to more than 1 table you should be using a modern and more efficient `JOIN` statement

Comment: sql statements are translated internally from the dbms so you can write it in both way, join strategy will be decided from the dbms so more efficient depends on the strategy selected internally